# Search in sql based on pattern

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have column `employee_no varchar2(6)`. I want to fetch all records which have `employee_no` like `010101`, `121212`, `232323`, etc. How to search based on this pattern?

Comment: Are those the *only* numbers you are looking for? It's a very odd choice of "demo data" - or does this mean that the pattern also extends to '898989'? What about '181818'?

Comment: i know that i could use wildcard and like. i want something like  x(x+1)x(x+1)x(x+1). i don`t want  write whole expected result in 'like' operator. I want use some regular expression.is this possible?

Comment: Even a regular expression can't handle this without providing all the initial sequence pairs (there is no `n`/`n+1` concept in a regex). Anyway .. I don't use Oracle, but see [Oracle 10g: Using Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#i1011021). The regex might look like: `(01|12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89){3}`. I have no idea how the query plans may differ.

Comment: (Whoops, instead of `{3}`, see capture groups in Ramblin's answer. However, note how the n/n+1 concept is *simulated*)

Comment: sorry for my  silly question. i thought   i  could make it more generalize  using some looping  rather than hard coding  pattern in like operator.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for employee numbers where a group of numbers repeat?
If so, then you can use REGEXP_LIKE.

```
select *
from yourtable
where regexp_like(employeeno, '(..)\1\1');
```

Breaking down the regex pattern,

```
(..)  --matches any two characters
\1    --matches the first group(the one in brackets)
\1    --matches the first group(the one in brackets)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/19623).

Comment: Note: This will match 000000 as presented.

Comment: Ramblin your query works.but can we generalize it  because in bracket i have to provide two character. Can we write logic in procedure and iterate characters in brackets like for first time it will have (01) for  2nd time (12). Thanks in advance

Comment: @saurabh "Best" that can be done is to provide a valid set of such pairs, as per my comment above.

Comment: @Ramblin.thanks for your reply. i thought i could make it more  generalize.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from yourtable where emp_no like '%010101%' OR emp_no like '%121212%' OR 
emp_no like '%232323%'
```

Comment: Since "I have column employee no varchar2(6)", then it seems like LIKE is not the most appropriate.